# Have detail view for transaction, transaction has a one to many relationship with sale. I want to display all sales with transaction in detail view

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

Im trying to display many side of a relationship in a detail view in django. A transaction can have many sales.

my view below:

class TransactionDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Transaction

URL Below:
path('transaction//', TransactionDetailView.as_view(), name='transaction-detail'),

HTML below:

```
<h1> Transaction</h1>
<br/>
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-12">
        <h4>Purchased Coins</h4>

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th scope="col">Coin</th>
                     <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                     <th scope="col">per Coin</th>
                     <th scope="col">Total</th>
                     <th scope="col">Value Per Coin</th>
                     <th scope="col">Total Value</th>
                     <th scope="col">Date Added</th>
                     <th scope="col">Profit/Loss</th>
                     <th scope="col">%Profit/Loss</th>
                 </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

             <tr>
                 <td>{{object.currency}}</td>
                 <td>{{object.amount}}</td>
                 <td>{{object.amount_per_coin}}</td>
                 <td>{{object.total_price}}</td>
                 <td><p>Get From API</p></td>
                 <td><p>{{object.amount}} * Get From API</p></td>
                 <td>{{object.date_purchased|date:"F d, Y"}}</td>
                 <td><p>TBC</p></td>
                 <td><p>TBC</p></td>
             </tr>

             </tbody>
        </table>
```

## trying to create list of sales associated with transaction

```
        {% for sale in object.sales %}
        <p>kkk</p>
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is use a [SingleObjectMixin with a ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-singleobjectmixin-with-listview), use the SingleObjectMixin to provide the `transaction` and ListView to list all its related `sales`.